# Finding bound on the solution of systems

Tags: dynamical-systems, upper-lower-bounds

Consider
$$
\begin{gathered}
\dot{x}_1=x_1 x_2 \\
\dot{x}_2=-x_2 .
\end{gathered}
$$

Show that
$$
\left|x_1(t)\right|+\left|x_2(t)\right| \leq \alpha\left(\left|x_1(0)\right|+\left|x_2(0)\right|\right),
$$
where
$$
\alpha(s) \triangleq s e^s .
$$

Here $\alpha$ denotes [K class function.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_kappa_function)

I found solution of $x_2$ and have $x_2(t)=x_2(0)e^{-t}$. Then I plugged that in the first equation and got $x_1(t)=x_1(0)e^{e^{-t}}$. I am not sure how to proceed with this proof.

Comment: It looks like your solution must have $x_2(0)=-1$

Comment: Do you mean to include the restriction $t\ge0$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, a correction: the solution to $\dot{x}_1=x_1x_2=x_1x_2(0)e^{-t}$ is
$$
x_1(t)=x_1(0)e^{x_2(0)(1-e^{-t})}. \tag{1}
$$
Now we have a sequence of straightforward inequalities: if $t\geq 0$, then
$$
|x_2(t)|=|x_2(0)e^{-t}|\leq |x_2(0)| \tag{2}
$$
and
$$
|x_1(t)|=\left|x_1(0)e^{x_2(0)(1-e^{-t})} \right|
\leq |x_1(0)|e^{|x_2(0)(1-e^{-t})|}
\leq |x_1(0)|e^{|x_2(0)|}. \tag{3}
$$
Therefore,
\begin{align}
|x_1(t)|+|x_2(t)|&\leq |x_1(0)|e^{|x_2(0)|}+|x_2(0)| \\
&\leq (|x_1(0)|+|x_2(0)|)e^{|x_2(0)|} \\
&\leq (|x_1(0)|+|x_2(0)|)e^{|x_1(0)|+|x_2(0)|} \\
&=\alpha(|x_1(0)|+|x_2(0)|). \quad{\square} \tag{4}
\end{align}

Comment: thank you very much!